# Merge two data tables with different time preferably in access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, merge, datatables

I appreciate if I could help on this issue. I am relatively beginner to database designs. I have two tables (see link below) which I would like to combine: 
Tbl_1:
Date, Product, Sold
Tbl_2: 
Date, Forecast_Year, Product, Prediction

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1kyuGEF0AZ-PaDUT1LiEGIgxW6ntlCDk1WVUT1jJ9Wxs/edit?pli=1#slide=id.p

Basically, every year we do a forecast on how much we can sale for the coming years and we store data on the second table while we have historical sale on the first table. I would like to know how in Access or SQL I can get the final combined table automatically. Tables 1 and 2 are updated regularly. Thanks for the help beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Most easiest would be to Merge the Query using a union statement

```
Select Date , Product , Sold , '' as [Forecast_Year], '' as [Prediction] FROM Table 1

UNION ALL

Select Year as [Date], Product, '' as [Sold], Forecast_Year , Prediction from Table 2
```

'' as `[Forecast_Year]` is basically a fixed empty value for the `Forecast_Year` column that you will use for each row in table 1.

Same goes for the other fixed value columns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this does not solve my problem. See Link below: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1kyuGEF0AZ-PaDUT1LiEGIgxW6ntlCDk1WVUT1jJ9Wxs/edit?pli=1#slide=id.p                                             in 2014, all columns of data in Final table should have values. This can be achieved by Union. Any other suggestion is appreciated? Can I design the tables in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive what you are looking for is UNION:

[Combine the results of several select queries by using a union query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Combine-the-results-of-several-select-queries-by-using-a-union-query-3856f16c-0a22-43f2-8c23-29ec44acbc05)